# Easy way to compute Jacobian for $f(z) = z^n$?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

As a function on $\mathbb R^2$, I want to compute the Jacobian of $f(z)=z^n$.
Is there an easy way to this? Write $z=x+iy$ .. and compute real part and imaginary part of $f$ and differentiate with respect to $x,y$ seems to be very tedious work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a holomorphic function $f$, its Jacobian matrix is  $\left(\begin{array}{cc}\mathrm{Re}~f' & -\mathrm{Im}~f'\\\mathrm{Im}~f' &\mathrm{Re}~f' \end{array}\right)$, and its Jacobian determinant is $|f'|^2$. Please see [Cauchy-Riemann equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) for reference.

Comment: I thought he meant the Jacobian *matrix*, not the *determinant*.

Comment: oh... I'm enough for determinant.

Comment: I thought I found some way.
since power function can easily be seen if we see in polar coordinate, try to see f as functions of r,theta and then try to apply chain rule

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: I have updated.

Comment: @mathlover: have you learned some complex analysis? If so, then compared with using polar coordinate, compute the complex derivative is a little more convenient in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=x+iy, \quad f(x,\ y)=u(x,\ y)+iv(x,\ y).$ Using polar coordinates 
\begin{gather}
x=\rho \cos{\varphi}\\
y=\rho \sin{\varphi}
\end{gather} 
and the chain rule, Jacobian matrix
\begin{gather}
\dfrac{\partial(u,\, v)}{\partial(x, \, y)}=\pmatrix{\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\ \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}}=\dfrac{\partial(u,\, v)}{\partial(\rho, \, \varphi)}\cdot
\dfrac{\partial(\rho, \, \varphi)}{\partial(x, \, y)}.
\end{gather}