# Compute the Jacobian matrix of $f(z,w)=(ze^{i\alpha},\ w)$

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

I have a question:

> Let $f$ be a holomorphic and $f(z,w)=(ze^{i \alpha},\ w)$ with $z,\ w \in \Bbb C$. Compute its Jacobian matrix.

I remember that:

For a holomorphic function $f$, its Jacobian matrix is 
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}\mathrm{Re}~f' & -\mathrm{Im}~f'\\\mathrm{Im}~f' &\mathrm{Re}~f' \end{array}\right)$$

Is is correct? And How do we calculate the Jacobian matrix of $f$?

---

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sort of shooting in the dark but I think I understand the main point

The Jacobian for a multivariable function f: from $R^n \rightarrow R^m$ with arguments $u_1 ... u_n$ is defined as

$$\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u_2 } \ \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u_1} ... \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u_n} \\ \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u_2 } \ \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u_1} ... \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u_n} \\ \vdots \ \ \ \  \  \  \ \vdots  \ \ \  \ \ddots  \ \  \ \ \vdots \\ \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u_2 } \ \frac{\partial F_m}{\partial u_m} ... \frac{\partial F_m}{\partial u_n} \end{bmatrix}  $$

Now you have an issue here in that there are two definitions of the Jacobian we are dealing with.

An Alternative Interpretation is to treat the entire Jacobian as the derivative of the function

and so the answer should take the form

$$\begin{bmatrix} Re\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u_2 } \ \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u_1} ... \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u_n} \\ \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u_2 } \ \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u_1} ... \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u_n} \\ \vdots \ \ \ \  \  \  \ \vdots  \ \ \  \ \ddots  \ \  \ \ \vdots \\ \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u_2 } \ \frac{\partial F_m}{\partial u_m} ... \frac{\partial F_m}{\partial u_n} \end{pmatrix}  && -Im\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u_2 } \ \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u_1} ... \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u_n} \\ \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u_2 } \ \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u_1} ... \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u_n} \\ \vdots \ \ \ \  \  \  \ \vdots  \ \ \  \ \ddots  \ \  \ \ \vdots \\ \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u_2 } \ \frac{\partial F_m}{\partial u_m} ... \frac{\partial F_m}{\partial u_n} \end{pmatrix} \\ Im\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u_2 } \ \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u_1} ... \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u_n} \\ \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u_2 } \ \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u_1} ... \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u_n} \\ \vdots \ \ \ \  \  \  \ \vdots  \ \ \  \ \ddots  \ \  \ \ \vdots \\ \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u_2 } \ \frac{\partial F_m}{\partial u_m} ... \frac{\partial F_m}{\partial u_n} \end{pmatrix} &&  Re\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u_2 } \ \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u_1} ... \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u_n} \\ \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u_2 } \ \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u_1} ... \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial u_n} \\ \vdots \ \ \ \  \  \  \ \vdots  \ \ \  \ \ddots  \ \  \ \ \vdots \\ \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial u_2 } \ \frac{\partial F_m}{\partial u_m} ... \frac{\partial F_m}{\partial u_n} \end{pmatrix}\end{bmatrix}   $$

Both answers carry the same data, I'm not exactly sure which is correct... Talk to your prof about this. My gut feeling now is that the latter convention seems more natural

Using the latter convention 
\begin{bmatrix} \begin{matrix} Re\left(e^{i \alpha} \right) & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} & \begin{matrix} -Im\left((e^{i \alpha}) \right) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \\  \begin{matrix} Im\left((e^{i \alpha}) \right) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}  & \begin{matrix} Re\left(e^{i \alpha} \right) & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \end{bmatrix}

Comment: I'm sorry when I say that I don't understand your formular!!! Can you post the result of $\text{Jacobian}f(z,w)=????$

Comment: $F_1$ is the first element of your function (in other words $ze^{ia}$), $F_2$ is the second element of your function (in other words $w$) the idea is that your function is inputting a list of values (z,w) and outputting another list. The first element of the output list is $F_1$ the second is $F_2$ etc... For each element we are allowed to take a partial derivative, i can elaborate further if you like

Comment: I'm sorry Because i'm a stupid girl! plz, can you post your result? Since your result I can check my ANS.

Comment: Bad Attitude but i will go ahead and post the two possible results if that makes things easier to interpret (not sure which convention is better)

Comment: @Downvoter I deleted my scratchwork, although to my defense if you read the entire thing you would've seen the right answer and formula anyways at the bottom :P

Comment: @ frogeyedpeas: Your result is:
$$\begin{bmatrix} \begin{matrix} \cos \alpha & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} & \begin{matrix} -\sin \alpha & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \\  \begin{matrix} \sin \alpha & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}  & \begin{matrix} \cos \alpha& 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \end{bmatrix}$$ Thanks you! ^_^

Comment: I suspect you have some index issues above.

Comment: @ copper.hat:????

Answer (score 0):

Just compute it directly:

$D f((z,w)) = \begin{bmatrix} { \partial f_1(z,w) \over \partial z} &
{ \partial f_1(z,w) \over \partial w} \\
{ \partial f_2(z,w) \over \partial z} &
{ \partial f_2(z,w) \over \partial w}
\end{bmatrix}  = 
\begin{bmatrix} e^{i \alpha} &
0 \\
0 &
1
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: I think she wants a complex valued Jacobian, I'm not sure how to distribute the reals and imaginaries of the derivatives, see her question's formula

Comment: It **is** a complex valued Jacobian.

Comment: There's a difference between the two types of jacobians: see this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226183/easy-way-to-compute-jacobian-for-fz-zn

Comment: I'm not perfectly sure how to reconcile the two definitions into a single framework but I've given my best attempt in my answer (at least the two likely candidates)

Comment: There is only one type of Jacobian. It is the derivative of the function $(z,w) \mapsto (z e^{i \alpha}, w)$.

Comment: That's what I thought till I saw her formula, then I looked and it appears others have been using her formula too and calling it a Jacobian when dealing with complex analysis questions. Thats whats throwing me off, did you click my link?

Comment: You can compute the partials whatever way you want, but the Jacobian is just the derivative.

Comment: Click the link, someone did exactly what you have done here, and someone did work using a totally different formula (the one she has) (or just rather gave the formula), and the normal jacobian wasn't accepted, but this other strange definition was. It has nothing to do with how partials are computed

Comment: My mistake, both methods Are the same in that link, and neither of them is the standard Jacobian from multivariable calculus

Comment: page 4 of this book explains the nuance: http://books.google.com/books?id=8UBYQz3Ro9cC&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=holomorphic+jacobian&source=bl&ots=OqFeTK4BUA&sig=qV7vb3-HofoaQCR8cCGEyXSrE4Q&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JxzjU4WgFJKQyASzuoG4BQ&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=holomorphic%20jacobian&f=false

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I personally prefer your answer, but it appears that this question is one of convention and choice of formula. I honestly don't see the point of breaking up real and imaginary parts but that appears to be the "conventional?" definition of the Jacobian in complex analysis judging by past answers and a textbook.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas: If you take the map $\phi:\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ given by $\phi((z_1,z_2)) = (\operatorname{re} z_1, \operatorname{re} z_2,\operatorname{im} z_1, \operatorname{im} z_1)$, then you can compute the Jacobian of the function $\phi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}: \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ and this will give you a real valued Jacobian, if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much copper.hat! I'll ask my teacher and he can check your ANS, also frogeyedpeas's formular.

Comment: @copper.hat: Do you agree with frogeyedpeas and his result? $$\text{Jacobian}(f)=\begin{bmatrix} \begin{matrix} \cos \alpha & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} & \begin{matrix} -\sin \alpha & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \\  \begin{matrix} \sin \alpha & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}  & \begin{matrix} \cos \alpha& 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: It depends on what you mean by a Jacobian. If you mean the derivative of a function $\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}^2$, then my answer is the Jacobian. If you mean the derivative of a function $\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$, then use @frogeyedpeas's answer.

Comment: yes, I mean that We consider $$f:U \subset \Bbb C^2 \to \Bbb C^2,\ (z,w) \mapsto f(z,w)=(ze^{i\alpha},w)$$

Comment: Then the Jacobian is given by the formula for $Df((z,w)) \in \mathbb{C}^{2 \times 2}$ in my answer above.